# How to create and control a form within another one synchronously using Invoke and Begin Invoke?

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates, invoke, begininvoke

I'm working on a project in which I need to run a form within another
for example i have two forms class: form1 and form2

in form1:

```
public void func1()
{
  form2 f=new form2();
  f.show();
  Thread.sleep(2000);  
}
```

when I run this, `f` which is an instance of form2 hangs till the thread wake up after 2 seconds.

I tried using another thread but it doesn't work correct. I know I should use `Invoke` and `BeginInvoke()` but I don't know how to use them here. I'm new to Delegate and Invoke and the more I read about that the more I'm being confused! Please help me.

**Edit1(More Info)**
The form1 is master form and the form2 is a simple form with a button
in form1 I create and show ther form2 as below:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public delegate void showdel();
        public Form2 f;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            f = new Form2();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(sstart);
            t.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
        }


        public void sstart()
        {
            f.Show();
        }

    }
```

but when i run this code the form2 appear for just a moment and disappear quickly. even when i try this code for sstart() it work the same:

```
public void sstart()
        {
            if (f.InvokeRequired == true)

                f.BeginInvoke(new showdel(sstart));

            else
                f.Show();
        }
```

i have the hang problem yet. but further i wanna control the form2 in the form1, for example change the title of the form 2. unfortuately i haven't much information about backgroundworker and how it works?
does anyone have any reference about it?

Comment: Do not perform blocking tasks in a UI thread.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: if Form2 should be the active controlling form, use `ShowDialog` instead of `Show`.  Otherwise you should be using a BackgroundWorker and Wait commands.  You need to get more specific on how Form2 is supposed to be used.

Comment: It hangs for two seconds because you are telling the main thread to sleep for two seconds.  Is this supposed to be a placeholder for an intensive operation?  You said you tried using another thread but "it didn't work" - how did it not work?  Did you get exceptions?  Show them to us.  Show us the code that "didn't work".  Explain what you expected it to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want form2 to Start and appear for only two seconds, I would add a timer to the constructor to close it.

```
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer Timer = new Timer();
        Timer.Interval = 2000;
        Timer.Enabled = true;
        Timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer_Tick);

    }
    private void Timer_Tick(object o, EventArgs a)
    {

            this.Close();
    }
```

May be a slightly better way to do this (Backgroundworker,etc).

Comment: thanks, but thread.sleep() is a sample. in real program i have a connection to a device that takes about 3 seconds, i think i should use backgroundworker, but i don't know where to start from? i mean a tutorial or a reference...

Comment: My suggestion: A) Start by declaring Form 2's identifier as a global and instancing it like you do. B) Just because you start another form doesn't mean it's in a separate thread. As long as you are in the same thread you can change anything from anywhere with just this.(Form2's variable).Title = "New Title"; 
This might help:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28EHINVALIDOPERATION.WINFORMS.ILLEGALCROSSTHREADCALL%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true